# oauth 1.0 -invalid signature GetRequestToken for Google 

Tags: javascript, oauth

I could not find any active Oauth 1.0  support by Google as it has already been deprecated.
But as I want to access Gmail data,I am bound to use Oauth 1.0

So I have been trying since 2 days to get the RequestToken for my Google Application and I am getting the invalid signature error.
My base-string matches with the debug-string returned by google.

I have tried using both HMAC-SHA1 and RSA-SHA1 and my keys are correct.
(I have even tried using both token and secret as anonymous which Google recommends for non-registered applications.)
Could it be something due to wrong nonce or due to some percent-encoding issue.
The same method worked fine for Twitter.

I am also pasting my code below and would be glad if someone could help or point me to the right forum.

```
    $('#GMAIL_BUTTON').click(function () {
    //oauth1 approach similar to twitter
    var requestUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
    var scope = "https://mail.google.com/";
    var clientID = "anonymous";
    var clientSecret = "anonymous";
    var rsakey = "MIICblahblahblah";
    var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
    var nonce = Math.random();        
    var sigBaseStringParams = "oauth_consumer_key=" + clientID;
    sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
    sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
    sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp;
    sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "scope=" + encodeURIComponent(scope);
    var sigBaseString = "GET&";
    sigBaseString += encodeURIComponent(requestUrl) + "&" +        encodeURIComponent(sigBaseStringParams) + "\n" + "\n";
    requestUrl += "?scope=https://mail.google.com/";
    var keyText = encodeURIComponent(clientSecret) + "&";
    //var keyText = rsakey;
    var keyMaterial =     Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(keyText, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    var macAlgorithmProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.MacAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
    var key = macAlgorithmProvider.createKey(keyMaterial);
    //var keyMaterial = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.decodeFromBase64String(rsakey);
    //var macAlgorithmProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm("RSASIGN_PKCS1_SHA1");
    //var key = macAlgorithmProvider.importKeyPair(keyMaterial);
    var tbs = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(sigBaseString, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    var signatureBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.sign(key, tbs);
    var signature =    Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(signatureBuffer);
    var dataToPost = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + clientID + "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\", oauth_signature=\"" + encodeURIComponent(signature) + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
    var response = sendGetRequest(requestUrl, dataToPost, null);
});
```

And the SendGetRequest method is -

```
   function sendGetRequest(url, authzheader, params) {
    try {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, false);
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authzheader);
        request.send(params);
        return request.responseText;
    } catch (err) {
        WinJS.log("Error sending request: " + err, "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any glaring errors in your code, but you'll probably have a much easier time using Google's OAuth 2 for client-side apps library at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent. Further, you may want to use the atom feed scope (https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom)--you can give it and other scopes a try at https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/.

Comment: The OP probably wants to access [GMail over IMAP/SMTP with OAuth](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) and not the unread mails atom feed. This is only available over OAuth 1.

Comment: thanks.i got over it.i thikn the problem was related to some URL encoding issues.

Comment: @gauravkejriwal Then post how you resolved it as answer.